# Angular directive invocation

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to define a directive and a module in Angular.js as follows (venue-map.js):

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('venues', []);

    app.directive('venueInfo', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "venue-info.html"
        };
    });
})();
```

where venue-info.html only contains a `<p>` element:

```
<p>WHY OH WHY</p>
```

However, when I try to invoke it on my HTML like this:

`<venueInfo></venueInfo>`

nothing appears on the screen. I believe I'm correctly importing both angular.js and my module script. This is my complete index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="venues">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="venue-map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <venueInfo></venueInfo>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <venue-info></venue-info>

Comment: To add to @rob's answer, Angular is [normalizing the directive names](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives), so hyphenated names become cameCased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<venue-info>` instead of `<venueInfo>`.

In Angular, you're supposed to use camelcase in js, but hyphenation in html.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code :

```
app.directive('venueInfo', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "venue-info.html",
        transclude: true
    };
});
```